# Calling method, classmethod, staticmethod in the same Python class

Tags: python, class

From a famous example, I learned the difference between method, classmethod and staticmethod in a Python class.

> Source:
>   [What is the difference between @staticmethod and @classmethod in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/what-is-the-difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod-in-python)

```
class A(object):
    def foo(self,x):
        print "executing foo(%s,%s)"%(self,x)

    @classmethod
    def class_foo(cls,x):
        print "executing class_foo(%s,%s)"%(cls,x)

    @staticmethod
    def static_foo(x):
        print "executing static_foo(%s)"%x   
    # My Guesses
    def My_Question(self,x):
        self.foo(x)
        A.class_foo(x)
        A.static_foo(x)

a=A()
```

Now I am wondering, how to call a method, `@classmethod`, and `@staticmethod` inside the class.

I put my guesses in the `My_Question` function above, please correct me if I am wrong with any of these.

Comment: What you have is correct.  It is also possible to use `self` for all 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your guesses will work.  Note that it is also possible/normal to call staticmethods and classmethods *outside* the class:

```
class A():
    ...

A.class_foo()
A.static_foo()
```

Also note that *inside* regular instance methods, it's customary to call the staticmethods and class methods directly on the instance (`self`) rather than the class (`A`):

```
class A():
    def instance_method(self):
        self.class_foo()
        self.static_foo()
```

This allow for inheritance to work as you might expect -- If I create a `B` subclass from `A`, if I call `B.instance_method()`, my `class_foo` function will get `B` instead of `A` as the `cls` argument -- And possibly, if I override `static_foo` on `B` to do something slightly different than `A.static_foo`, this will allow the overridden version to be called as well.

Some examples might make this more clear:

```
class A(object):
    @staticmethod
    def static():
        print("Static, in A")

    @staticmethod
    def staticoverride():
        print("Static, in A, overrideable")

    @classmethod
    def clsmethod(cls):
        print("class, in A", cls)

    @classmethod
    def clsmethodoverrideable(cls):
        print("class, in A, overridable", cls)

    def instance_method(self):
        self.static()
        self.staticoverride()
        self.clsmethod()
        self.clsmethodoverride()

class B(A):
    @classmethod
    def clsmethodoverrideable(cls):
        print("class, in B, overridable", cls)

    @staticmethod
    def staticoverride():
        print("Static, in B, overrideable")


a = A()
b = B()
a.instance_method()
b.instance_method()
```

...

After you've run that, try it by changing all of the `self.` to `A.` inside `instance_method`.  Rerun and compare.  You'll see that all of the references to `B` have gone (even when you're calling `b.instance_method()`).  This is why you want to use `self` rather than the class.

Comment: I saw in the top answer in the referenced post saying that, a @classmethod is bounded to the class, and have to include a 'cls' just like 'self' for a normal class method. I am wondering are the 'cls' and 'self' has any actual meaning, so that we must use those 2 strings? And also why not use cls.class_foo(x) instead of self.class_foo(x)?

Comment: The names `self` and `cls` are _conventions_.  You can use any name you want, but anyone reading your code will likely yell at you very loudly if you deviate from the normal conventions :-).  In a `classmethod`, the first argument is the _class_ whereas in a normal method, the first argument is an _instance_ of the class.   It's the difference between `A` and `a` in your example code. -- As to "why not use `cls.class_foo(x)`" -- You _would_ use that if you were calling one classmethod from another classmethod.  In an instance method, the name `cls` isn't defined (try it with my example code).

Answer (score 1):

As @wim said, what you have is right. Here's the output when `My_Question` is called.

```
>>> a.My_Question("My_Answer=D")
executing foo(<__main__.A object at 0x0000015790FF4668>,My_Answer=D)
executing class_foo(<class '__main__.A'>,My_Answer=D)
executing static_foo(My_Answer=D)
```