# Use self or type(self) to call static methods and class methods within a class

Tags: python

I had a question about the preferred way of calling static and class methods within a class in Python ( >= 2.7).

From this resource [Calling method, classmethod, staticmethod in the same Python class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47088492/calling-method-classmethod-staticmethod-in-the-same-python-class), I can understand why it is better to use `self` over the class name to call static methods. My question is if it is better to use `self` or `type(self)` when trying to call static/class methods within a class?

```
class A:
    pass


class B(A):
    @staticmethod
    def f():
        return 5

    def g_option1(self):
        return type(self).f()

    def g_option2(self)
        return self.f()
```

Comment: Better is option2.  Best is not to use static methods at all.

Comment: I use 3.x, and there is a difference between classmethod and staticmethod annotations. You should read up on them both

Comment: I don't think I understand your question, because what I thought it was was answered in the question you linked.

Comment: @wim If we should not use static methods at all, then what type of methods should we use if we want to keep those methods specific to the class?

Comment: Because if the "method" doesn't need any information about the instance nor the class, then it may as well be a module level function in the first place. Python is not Java, no need to overcomplicate matters in order to be faithful to Java's datamodel or some OOP ideology.

Comment: @wim I disagree, some classes hold "certain types" of functions as static methods because they all relate to each other, or because it's a logical convinience to import them together

Comment: @OferSadan Such conveniences are already adequately provided by the module namespace.